# How to add worksheet after the last sheet of the workbook?

Tags: excel, delphi

I'm generating an Excel sheet with Delphi, but the problem I'm facing is that when I use this code:

```
Workbook.Sheets.Add;
```

the new sheet is added before the currently selected worksheet:

[image]

Does anyone know how to add a worksheet after the last sheet of the workbook ?

Comment: FYI, the [`Worksheets.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheets.add.aspx) method has 4 optional parameters.

Comment: `Workbook.Sheets.Add.After;`  Would do the trick?

Comment: Maybe like `Workbook.Sheets.Add(NULL, Workbook.Sheets.Count)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Add` method accepts parameters for you to indicate where to insert the new sheet, in particular the `After` parameter. It should be a reference to the sheet to insert the new sheet after. In your case, you want the last sheet. `Worksheets` is a 1-based array, so the last sheet is given by `Worksheets[Worksheets.Count]`. Putting it all together, we get this:

```
Workbook.Worksheets.Add(After := Workbook.Worksheets[Workbook.Worksheets.Count]);
```

Answer (score 2):

To add a new sheet we need to use the method .Sheets.Add, it has five parameters (the sheet before it, the sheet after it, and other 3,only god knows) in this case i used (NULL,aSheet,NULL,NULL,0)  where aSheet to insert it after the last one.
bye

```
uses
        ... OleServer,  ExcelXP ...
    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Button1: TButton;
        ExcelApplication1: TExcelApplication;
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;    
   ...      
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
    Excelfile:OleVariant;
    aBook: _WORKBOOK;
    aSheet: _WORKSHEET;
    begin
    Excelfile:='c:\plantilla.xls';
    ExcelApplication1.connect;
    aBook:= ExcelApplication1.workbooks.add(Excelfile,0);        

    aSheet:= ExcelApplication1.sheets[aBook.Sheets.Count] as _WORKSHEET;
    aBook.Sheets.Add(NULL,aSheet,NULL,NULL,0);

    aSheet:= ExcelApplication1.sheets[aBook.Sheets.Count] as _WORKSHEET;
    asheet.Name:='Test last position';

    ExcelApplication1.visible[0]:=true;
    ExcelApplication1.disconnect;
    end;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We generally prefer for answers to include some *sentences* answering the question, along with some code to demonstrate, if necessary. Code by itself does a poor job of answering a question because it forces readers to inspect the code very carefully to understand exactly which part of the code is really relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: This is early bound. Asker is using late bound.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think is the same.. you can create the file..or open it.. then the way to add sheets is the same.

Comment: I don't think so. Calling methods different late and early bound. You can pass EmptyParam early bound, but you gotta pass them all. Early bound you can pass just one.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I mean.. in THIS case.. the fact of adding  sheets is always late Bound I guess.. the file is ready in both cases, whether is created or just is ready.anyway, the guy who knows here is the Ghostbuster's guy :)  Thanks bye

Answer (score -1):

Using the after parameter is correct, but I am also finding that I need to use Type.Missing for the other parameters that I'm not specifying